# I Want to connect Azure blob storage with Angular app Through NodeJS Express app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, azure-blob-storage

What I actually want to do is that I don't really want to **make files upload directly** from the angular web app to **Azure blob storage**. Instead, I want to first send the uploaded file to **NodeJS** app through **express API** and then from their upload it to the azure app if I can actually do so. I don't think that uploading the file directly from the angular web app is secure because it will **reveal** my **azure blob storage credentials** that's why I want to upload it through **NodeJS** app.
If there is a **solution** of this problem then please tell me.
Or if the **solution is a bit different** but secure then still I want to know it.
And also share where I can get a **demo code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for Node.js and JavaScript for Browsers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage)

The flow will be like this: Your angular app will pass the data to the api as datastream. The API will then store it to the blob on the place that you configure in Azure Config details.

Comment: If you have or have seen some working code for that type of task than can you please provide that, I don't actually get the meaning of "data to the API as datastream", by that do you mean enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: Yes. This is how you send it from front end:
   UploadDocument(formData) {
    let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.localStorageService.getValue('access_token')
        })
    };
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/api/Documents/UploadDocuments', formData, options);
}

Comment: var stream = require('stream');
 var azure = require('azure-storage');
 var fileService = azure.createFileService();
 
 var fileStream = new stream.Readable();
 fileStream.push(myFileBuffer);
 fileStream.push(null);
 
 fileService.createFileFromStream('taskshare', 'taskdirectory', 'taskfile', fileStream, myFileBuffer.length, function(error, result, response) {
   if (!error) {
     // file uploaded
   }
 });

Comment: The first comment is from Angular Frontend and second is the example code from nodejs.